# SQL date field not showing properly in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I tried showing MSSQL data in a HTML table using Angular JS ng-repeat.
My date column field is shown in detailed with timezone etc:

> {"date":"2016-12-11 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}

I just want to show the date alone. How to format that?

```
<tr ng-repeat="bill in allbills | filter : search" >
    <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>   
    <td>{{ bill.bill_Date }}</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: angular has a built-in date filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `date` `filter`:

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

Your `<td>` should look something like this to display only date:

```
<td>{{ bill.bill_Date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
```

---

**EDIT**

You can also write a custom `filter` since you are already getting the date in correct format. Check [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/divyanshu013/cjw853fm/1/) fiddle with working code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span>{{ bill.bill_Date.date | date}}</span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.bill = { // from row set
      'bill_Date': {
        "date": "2016-12-11 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
      }
    };
  })
  .filter('date', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return input.split(' ')[0];
    }
  });
```

Comment: i used like this <td>{{ bill.bill_Date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>. but stil it displays with complete format.. remember it comes from SQL Server rowset.. it displays  {"date":"2016-12-11 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}

Comment: Do you want to display it as 2016-12-11 ?

Comment: I've added a custom filter, check it out.